# MVVM Group Radio Button

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, radio-button, radio-group

What is the best way of binding a number of RadioButtons to an enum using MVVM?

The only way I can think of is binding each group box's IsChecked to a property, and in the setter of that property assign a value to an enum in the view model.

Comment: Similar to question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029180/how-can-i-create-a-bound-list-of-radiobuttions-with-tooltips-in-xaml/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could display the Enum values in a ListBox and provide a special `ItemTemplate` with a RadioButton plus the name of the Enum. The RadioButton's `IsChecked` property could then be bound to the ListBoxItem's `IsSelected` property. Of course, you would have to set the ListBox's `SelectionMode` to `Single`.

Comment: Didn't thinks of that :) Will give it a try :D