# How Can I Create a Bound List of RadioButtions with ToolTips in Xaml?

Tags: xaml, listbox, radio-button, tooltip, listboxitem

I want to create a list of logically related RadioButtons. The RadioButtons are bound for MVVM use. There's ToolTips on each RadioButtons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Style that creates a group of logically related RadioButtons by using a ListBox. MyClass contains two String properties: MyName and MyToolTip. The style will display the list of RadioButtons including properly functioning individual ToolTips. This is an all bound, all Xaml solution for MVVM use.

Example usage:

ListBox Style="{StaticResource radioListBox}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyClasses}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedMyClass}"/>

Style:

```
    <Style x:Key="radioListBox" TargetType="ListBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBox}}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                <RadioButton Focusable="False" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}" Content="{Binding MyName}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding MyToolTip}" />
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```